# xml-not-well-formed error in when I try to bind resource in XMPP over Bosh

Tags: xmpp

## 1 Problem: I am getting xml not well formed error, when I try to bind resource in XMPP over Bosh.

What I tried: I went to xmpp.org to look for proper xml stanza for binding resource(http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html#preconditions-sasl), but it seems similar.

Possible answer: I havn't restarted the stream after authentication, can that be the cause of this error?

## 2 problem: I tried to restart the stream by using the packet(http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html#preconditions-sasl) but I got 400 in response code? Any body has any idea why I got that?

Possible answer: I didn't get xmpp:restartLogic attribute in response to initial packet? Can that be the reason for getting 400 error(May be Ejabbered server doesn't support restart)?

Doubt: Anyone got any idea on how to enable restartlogic in Ejabberd or is it enabled by default?

My Log is as follow:

```
Stanza to read is  = body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='8d96d01bb87f526e78b0f0b620dd1c94edd172ee' wait='30' requests='2' inactivity='30' maxpause='120' polling='2' ver='1.8' from='someserver.com' secure='true' authid='2817580747' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmpp:version='1.0'
Stanza to read is  = stream:features xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
Stanza to read is  = mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'
Stanza to read is  = mechanism
Stanza to read is  = c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='U5DC02T7iwEqfov5b3KpIVgA5+I='/
Stanza to read is  = register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/
Session creation response received: body secure=true requests=2 inactivity=30 authid=2817580747 sid=8d96d01bb87f526e78b0f0b620dd1c94edd172ee polling=2 xmlns=http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind wait=30 xmpp=urn:xmpp:xbosh ver=1.8 version=1.0 from=someserver.com stream=http://etherx.jabber.org/streams maxpause=120 == 
        features stream=http://etherx.jabber.org/streams == 
                mechanisms xmlns=urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl == 
                        mechanism == PLAIN
                        mechanism == DIGEST-MD5
                        mechanism == SCRAM-SHA-1
                c ver=U5DC02T7iwEqfov5b3KpIVgA5+I= node=http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ hash=sha-1 xmlns=http://jabber.org/protocol/caps == 
                register xmlns=http://jabber.org/features/iq-register == 
Authenticating: body secure=true requests=2 inactivity=30 authid=2817580747 sid=8d96d01bb87f526e78b0f0b620dd1c94edd172ee polling=2 xmlns=http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind wait=30 xmpp=urn:xmpp:xbosh ver=1.8 version=1.0 from=someserver.com stream=http://etherx.jabber.org/streams maxpause=120 == 
        features stream=http://etherx.jabber.org/streams == 
                mechanisms xmlns=urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl == 
                        mechanism == PLAIN
                        mechanism == DIGEST-MD5
                        mechanism == SCRAM-SHA-1
                c ver=U5DC02T7iwEqfov5b3KpIVgA5+I= node=http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ hash=sha-1 xmlns=http://jabber.org/protocol/caps == 
                register xmlns=http://jabber.org/features/iq-register == 
Using plain authorization
writtenToAir [0]: AE1haGlAdGVzdC5yYXBpZHNvZnR0ZWNobm9sb2d5LmNvbQBtYWhp
Starting PLAIN authorization
Stanza to read is  = body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'
Stanza to read is  = success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/
writtenToAir [0]: Resource
Binding resource
Stanza to read is  = body type='terminate' condition='remote-stream-error' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
Stanza to read is  = stream:error
Stanza to read is  = xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/
```

Comment: I got the answer. Actually I was suppose to send both restart and resource binding packet at same time.